# drupal 7 content type programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I want to create modules for my content types. Looking over the drupal field api as well as some examples of creating content types programmatically, i have a basic module. But theres a few things I can't seem to get working.

On text_with_summary, I have no idea how to set the number of rows, and how to set it so it actually has the summary. I've tried numerous settings in my code, and my field still has 20 rows, and the summary is unchecked. Be happy if anyone can even point me toward some good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to look at the examples modules when trying to learn.

http://drupal.org/project/examples